# Client socket sends but Silent Server socket doesn't recieve

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp, serversocket, tcpsocket

I've a Client Socket that pushes Image Data to Server Socket after connection Handshake is done. and the Server sockets process them *without responding anything*

It works well for few minutes. But After sometime the Server socket stops getting those Data. That I couldn't figure out why ? Is there any such thing in TCP like if client keep pushing data the server must say something otherwise the conversation will stop ?

I wrote this code years ago. and to make it work I made the server returning a string "ACK" response. However If I change that to any string it will work.

But now I want to figure out the Why to reconstruct the Program.

Answer (score 0):

"One-way" communication with TCP is totally fine unless you need an acknowledgment from the receiver on the sending side. But that's your application-level protocol. At the transport level the packets still flow both ways - TCP keeps sequence numbers in both directions and acknowledges them to the other side. This allows for detecting dropped/duplicate packets and for re-transmission, thus providing reliability of the stream. The window sizes negotiated during connection handshake and updated during the life of the conversation allow TCP to slow down fast sender that would overwhelm a slow receiver.

What you really need to do is to record the TCP connection with a sniffer like [`tcpdump(1)`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and find out what happens on the wire at the point when "socket stops getting those Data".

Comment: I sniffed the traffic with wireshak. What I saw is Client keeps sending. but server not receiving any of those packets after few minutes.

Comment: Are you sure the server actually reads from the socket? Does the server machine send TCP ACKs?

Comment: Yes otherwise how it works for first few minutes. What I observed is Client pushes packets first and server processes it, and it works fast for few minutes. and after that it looks like a trafic over flow that jams the trafic But It should be well handled by underlying TCP. However Surprisingly it not.

Comment: That's not a useful comment. There's no magic here. If you keep reading from the socket that has pending data, you get data. Check your code again - do you do anything after receiving your image that might block? Like locking a mutex, opening another socket, waiting on some input? Sniff the connection on the server side. Do you get data segments? Does the server TCP window close to zero?